# Text alignment after breakline

Tags: crystal-reports

I use this code for on some enumerations in a Textfield, (Code is stored in a formula and is set to html interpretation).

```
<li>Test; bla bla bla <br> bla bla</li>
```

Text after the `<br>` is not aligned with the starting point of the enumeration.
I have tried `<div>` and `<p>` but not these were not the solution.

In Crystal Reports 2013 it looks like:

```
      -List Item
 asfdsf
```

I want to have it like this:

```
- List item
  bsdgdsgfd
```

Comment: have you tried giving required spaces after `<br>`

Comment: yes- nothing happens because it is html interprated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is you can use `&nbsp`

Count the number of spaces it can take and change like this:

```
<li>Test; bla bla bla <br> &nbsp&nbsp bla bla</li> //suppose it takes two spaces so two times &nbsp&nbsp
```